# Sorting array by key works on iOS but not on Anroid

Tags: android, ios, arrays, react-native

I want to sort my array by date in ascending order. It works perfectly on iOS, but does nothing on Android.

```
    const sortedUnits = units.sort((b, a) => b.date > a.date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try comparison function that returns `number`, not `boolean`:

```
const sortedUnits = units.sort((b, a) => b.date - a.date);
```

(suppose, `date` field is timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

```
units.sort(function (left, right) {
          return moment.utc(a.date).diff(moment.utc(b.date))
  });
```